# Lazy "and" expression evaluation

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation, boolean-expression

I've been using the following code block to ask user for input and checking its validity in a console application.

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter X value:");    // prompt
} while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out temp) && (temp<=10) && (temp>=0))); // repeat if input couldn't be parsed as an integer or out of range
```

Is it a documented feature that the "&&" (and) expression evaluating is lazy? ie: if first operand is false then it wouldn't parse the second operand? Can I rely on it in production builds? Can I expect that it would behave the same in other compilers?
This is something I picked up in PPCG.SE

Additionally, can the block be made simpler to read or simplified into a oneliner?

Comment: It's amazing what one can find, if one is simply willing to [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator): _"The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a documented feature that the "&&" (and) expression evaluating
>   is lazy?

[Yes as mentioned on the C# reference page:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)

The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, **but only evaluates its second operand if necessary**. In other words, *it's a short-circuiting operator*.

> Can I rely on it in production builds? Can I expect that it would
>   behave the same in other compilers?

Yes, it should always behave the same.

> Additionally, can the block be made simpler to read or simplified into
>   a oneliner?

Apart from removing some of the redundant parameters, you cannot simplify this with only one line.

You can, however, make it a bit more readable by hiding the logic of `(temp<=10) && (temp>=0)` into some method e.g.:

```
public static bool IsValidRange(int temp) =>  temp >= 0 && temp <= 10;
```

then your while condition becomes:

```
while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp) && IsValidRange(temp)));
```

now the name of the method reads as the problem statement `IsValidRange`.

Comment: As an added note, `&&` and `||` are generally referred to as "short-circuit operators" because of this behavior.  Most major programming languages treat them this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant section in the C# Language Specification that talks about `&&` and `||`:

> Section 7.12 Conditional Logical Operators
>
> The && and || operators are conditional versions of the & and |
>   operators:
>
> - The operation x && y corresponds to the operation x & y,
>     except that y is evaluated only if x is not false.
> - The operation x || y corresponds to the operation x | y, except that y is evaluated only
>     if x is not true.

Since it's in the spec, it should behave the same no matter what compiler you use. If it doesn't, then the compiler you are using is not considered a "C#" compiler. :)